# How to give admin privileges for a Microsoft dev box user inside Dev box?

Tags: azure, elevated-privileges, azure-dev-box

I created a dev box, but I need to install some software on the machine.  It requires login  to have admin privileges inside dev box.  How do I access the Dev box with admin privileges?

I created a dev box and logged into it with Azure AD user account.  I found that I do not have Admin rights on the user. Just checking how to provide Admin privileges.

Answer (score 0):

When you created the [Dev Box Pool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dev-box/quickstart-configure-dev-box-service?tabs=AzureADJoin#5-create-a-dev-box-pool), you would have had the option to configure `Dev box Creator Privileges` to `Local Administrator`.

[image]